# Swift framework integration - Xcode shows errors but compiles ok

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, carthage

I have created a Swift framework and I have integrated that framework into my project using Carthage. All the necessary steps mentioned on the Carthage github page have been completed.

When I use the framework classes in my main project code, Xcode throws up errors in the editor (red exclamations in the margin) for any framework type - Use of undeclared type .... However the project itself compiles fine and works perfectly with the framework functionality. Another related issue might be that I do not get any autocomplete suggestions for my framework code. The framework classes, structs etc have been marked public as necessary.

What step am I missing here - what do I need to do so that Xcode does not show those errors?

The framework code is written on Xcode 8 with Swift 2.3, the main project is being managed on Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.3

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.3 - As far I know, Xcode 7.3.1 supported only till Swift 2.2

Comment: tried clean, vlean build folder and build?

Comment: Yes, I did try clean folder and build. That does nto help. But you are right about the different swift versions. I'll try upgrading my project to Swift 2.3 and check. That may be the problem. I'm not sure why it still works fine, I thought swift binary versions were incompatible

Comment: @prabodhprakash The Swift version was indeed the problem. For some reason I thought that we already had Swift 2.3 in Xcode 7. Please add an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks

Comment: Added my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 7.3.1 supported only till Swift 2.2. Please upgrade your project to Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8